# How to redirect someone to the error page without changing the url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a 'error 404' page using C# and asp.net. The problem is, when the user types [www.example.com/asdasd](http://www.example.com/asdasd) he is redirected to my error 404 page, but I wanted the url to stay the same.

For example, the user types 'www.example.com/asdasd', I wanted to stay 'www.example.com/asdasd' not 'www.example.com/error' (which is the name of my error 404 page that I'm wrongly redirecting).

This is my 'Custom Errors' inside my web.config file

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error/" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/" />
</customErrors>
```

This is my function inside Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            if (ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 404)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/error");
            }
        }
```

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: For the `customErrors` XML set `redirectMode` to `"ResponseRewrite"` - do you actually need the `Application_Error` code as well?

Comment: I've already tried this and it didnt worked @AlexK. and i need the `Application_Error`, otherwise my error url will contain and aspx error path, been something like `www.example.com/error.aspxerrorpath=asdasd`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like: Server.Transfer("~/error"). This 'transfers' the request server side to the desired page without a redirect (which involves a response and another request to the error page).

Comment: it returned me this error 'System.Web.HttpException: 'Error executing child request for /error.'

Comment: @Matheus You could try something like this, it's very similar to how the answer works - `Response.Clear(); var rd = new RouteData(); rd.DataTokens["area"] = ""; rd.Values["controller"] = "Errors"; rd.Values["action"] = "Error"; new ErrorController().Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd)); Server.ClearError();`

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Configure` method in `Startup.cs` class use `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` middleware:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{ 
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("~/error");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately im developing in ASP.NET not ASP.NET Core so i dont have the Startup.cs file. There is another way or file that i can put this function ?

Comment: I apologise I didn't see the topic was about the ASP.NET. I am not able to help you since I work with ASP.NET Core. Take a look at this article, it might be useful: https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages/

Comment: I've tried everything that this article says and still with the same problem